# Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible

Tags: java, databricks, databricks-connect

I'm using Python to access Databricks through `databricks-connect`. Behind the wall, this uses spark which is indeed java based so in order to use this, I need java. The JDK has been downloaded (version 14), set as JAVA_HOME env but when I run the code, I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to
> make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module
> java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @bccb269

This is the code where it crashes

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

I googled but couldn't find this error, I don't think it's the first time occurring to me. Any ideas what this error means and how can I fix it?

Comment: It means that library is trying to hack a Java core library, which is not allowed starting in Java 9.  The easiest solution is to stick with Java 8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Databricks Runtimes and databricks-connect won't work with Java 14. Only DBR 10.x have an experimental support for Java 11, but I doubt that it's supported for databricks-connect.

You need to install Java 8 to use databricks-connect.

Answer (score 3):

I had to

- Install Java 8, eg

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

- add $JAVA_HOME to my ~/.zshrc

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home'
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

- remove any other jdk installs

```
ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
sudo rm -rf NONJDK8.jdk
```

The 3rd bit is important! It did not work until I removed other-versioned jdks.